# Natural join on in SQL

Tags: sql, join

```
TableA                            TableB
Column1    Column2                Column3    Column4
1          2                      1          3
```

I have two table TableA(Column1,Column2) and TableB(Column3,Column4).I want to join two table using column1 ,column4(LIKE NATURAL JOIN). Is in SQL any things to join two table and return a new table with deleting repeated columns?

I want select this:

```
column1  column2  column4
1        2        3
```

Comment: I want things like 'natrual join on tableA.column1 = tableB.column3

Comment: If you're joining on `A.Column1 = B.Column3`, why did you say `Column1, Column4` above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DBMSes that support `NATURAL JOIN` require the column names of the join keys to match, and if you do `SELECT *` you will get only the unique column names. It doesn't make sense to try to specify column names, because the whole thing works by the names already being the same.

You MUST have same-named columns between the two tables, as it will use **every** same-named column between them to perform the join. Your tables `TableA` and `TableB` are unsuitable for a natural join as they don't share any column names.

So you are relegated to doing a regular join:

```
SELECT
   A.*, -- you can at least get all the columns from one table
   B.Column4 -- but you have to specify the rest one at a time
FROM
   TableA A
   INNER JOIN TableB B
      ON A.Column1 = B.Column3
;
```

You just have to bite the bullet and write the query. You may want to not have to write the column names, but *that's just not possible*.

Some notes: When you say "return a new table", I think I know what you mean, but technically it is a *rowset* since to be a table it would have to be stored in the database with a name.

It *may* be possible to alias the column in a view or inline derived table, but you haven't told us what specific DBMS you're using so we can answer for its exact capabilities. It **might** look something like this:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   TableA A
   NATURAL JOIN (
      SELECT Column1 = Column3, Column4
      FROM TableB B
   ) B
;
```

But notice that you still have to list all the *other* columns in `TableB` in order to do this. And I'm not even sure it works.

Comment: I Want to not write column names

Comment: Thanks @ErikE ! that was my question

Answer (score 1):

Joining two tables and querying on some or all columns doesn't return you a new table but record set. To get what you wanted try this. Below query adheres to SQL standard and thus should work on all SQL compliant databases.

```
SELECT ta.column1, ta.column2, tb.column4 from TableA ta INNER JOIN TableB tb ON     (ta.column1 = tb.column4)
```

If you want to use Natural Join, you need to have same columns.

Answer (score 1):

'Distinct' statement prevents repeating the similar rows too

```
SELECT Distinct
   TableA.Column1,
   TableA.Column2,
   TableB.Column4
FROM
   TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Column1 = TableB.Column3
```

Comment: I know Erik... I thought he is gonna avoid of repeating rows...But as an answer, I agree with your post too. (Table.* or Table.Column or 'NATURAL JOIN' statement)